# Multiple Steps Form in React

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I was asked to develop a multi-step form in React. The form contains 30 fields to be filled and it should be displayed in 3 steps of 10 fields each.
The first 2 steps have "Save" and "Next step" options to save the current work or continue with the next step.
The final step has "Save" and "Finish form" options, both of them will save the form in the database (through a web service).

Something like this:
[image]

The project is made on React, using Mobx for the state management, and **I'm new to react**. My question here is... how should i manage the states and the stores?
Should i have a single Store (FormStore) with the 30 fields and pass it to each component through the props and they will fill each field?
Is there any way i can have a single store (like a singleton) and each component fills its fields there?

I have to manage the fields information in memory untill the Save button is hit. And if when the Save button is hit, i need to save just the filled fields.

Any kind of guide will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this form data is not changed anywhere else in your application, you can use a single store for all. I cannot think of any disadvantage given that it is relatively small.

You would want to split it if the answers could be put in different categories and different categories would be mutated by different functionalities of your app.

Comment: Hello Julien and thanks for the help! So i should create one store (FormStore) which will ve imported in the container of the form and passed through props to each Step Page?

Comment: Yes. Using state for something that concerns more than one component looks wrong. Pass your stored form data as a prop in all the forms.

Comment: Sounds great! I was affraid that passing stores through components may be not something good. Thank you ver much sir!